# Regarding create index and lock word in SQL statement used for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

This way someone creates an index.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QueueSlow](
[QueueID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[QueueDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Status] [int] NOT NULL,
[TextData] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [PK_QueueSlow] ON [dbo].[QueueSlow]
(
[QueueID] ASC
)
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_QuerySlow] ON [dbo].[QueueSlow]
(
[QueueDateTime] ASC,
[Status] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [Title])
GO
```

I have question that when creating non-clustered index like

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_QuerySlow] ON [dbo].[QueueSlow]
(
[QueueDateTime] ASC,
[Status] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [Title])
GO
```

so what is the meaning of `INCLUDE([Title])` - does it mean a non-clustered index will be created on `Title` column?

Here is a SQL statement with lock keyword.

```
declare @Batch table (QueueID int, QueueDateTime datetime, _
Title nvarchar(255), TextData nvarchar(max) )

insert into @Batch
select Top (@BatchSize) QueueID, QueueDateTime, Title, TextData from QueueSlow
WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
where Status = 0
order by QueueDateTime ASC
```

When inserting data into a table variable then why would anyone use lock like

```
WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
```

What is the meaning of `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` ??

Is this statement `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` compatible with SQL Server 2000/2005 ?

Looking for a discussion. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Three questions in one ....

OK, here are some answers:

The `INCLUDE(Title)` option is new in SQL Server 2005. It does **NOT** create an index on that column - the index is created on `(QueueDateTime, Status)` only. But in the leaf level of that non-clustered index, the `Title` column's value is **included** - so if you have a query something like:

```
SELECT QueueDateTime, Title
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE QueueDateTime > (some value) AND Status = 1
```

then this query can be satisfied by using just the index leaf level pages - the index **covers** the query - you don't need to go back to the actual data tables to get your answer to your query.

This can very significantly improve performance, and increase scalability, too.

See a [good explanation of the benefits of including columns in non-clustered indexes here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/included+columns/69179/).

As for the `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` - you should check out [this other SO question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524155/what-effect-does-holdlock-have-on-updlock) and the excellent answer provided by Andrew. And [here's yet another question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843733/confused-about-updlock-holdlock) with an excellent answer by Remus Rusanu.

Both table hints were available at least since SQL Server 2000 (or possibly even earlier - I can't remember versions earlier than that, though).

Comment: And this (outside SO) very long and detailed article (and not only about UPDLOCK hint): [Developing Modifications that Survive Concurrency](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/developing-modifications-that-survive-concurrency/)

Comment: please tell me briefly what is the use of (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK). when one should use it? what is the advantage of (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)?

Comment: @Thomas: see those questions and answers I linked to - no point in repeating those statements here again....

Answer (score 3):

First, read [Using Tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/).

> So what is the meaning of INCLUDE([Title]) - does it mean a non-clustered index will be created on Title column?

No. It means the index will *include* the Title  as extra info. A query can lookup rows by the indexed fields `([Status], [QueueDateTime])` (hint: this is the correct order of your keys) and retrieve *also* the value of the `Title` w/o looking up the base table.

> When inserting data into a table variable then why would anyone use lock like `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)`

The hints (which are incidentally incorrect) apply to the SELECT, not to the INSERT.

> Is this statement WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) compatible with SQL Server 2000/2005 ?

Yes. Here is the [SQL Server 2000 spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and here is the [SQL Server 2005 spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). But is, as I said, incorrect. Forcing serialization isolation level (which the HOLDLOCK hint is) is a sure-shot way to tank your throughput.

To do what you want you should make the `[QueueId]` a non-clustered primary key constraint and the clustered index should be `([Status], [QueueDateTime])`. The SELECT hint should be `(UPDLOCK, READPAST)`. A much better approach, based on [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) is presented in the article I first linked.

Comment: please tell me briefly what is the use of (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK). when one should use it? what is the advantage of (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)?